# How do I narrow "sex" of a Senior Nurse and Nurse as only ("F") Female?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supposed to List the first name and surname of every staff member who is neither a surgeon
nor a male nurse and group the list by town and sort each town by age in descending
order.

```
select first_name, surname, staff_type, sex, town, extract(year from  sysdate) - extract (year from birth_date ) age
    from staff, person
    where staff.person_id = person.person_id
    and staff_type != 'Surgeon'
    minus
    select first_name, surname, staff_type, sex, town,  extract(year from sysdate) - extract (year from birth_date ) age
    from staff, person
    where staff.person_id = person.person_id
    and person.sex = 'F'
    union 
    select first_name, surname, staff_type, sex, town,  extract(year from sysdate) - extract (year from birth_date ) age
    from staff, person
    where staff.person_id = person.person_id
    and staff_type = 'Anaesthetist'
    order by town desc, age desc;
```

[image: The current Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select p.first_name, 
       p.surname,
       s.staff_type,
       p.sex,
       p.town,
       extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from p.birth_date) age
from staff s join person p on s.person_id = p.person_id
where s.staff_type <> 'Surgeon'
  and s.person_id not in -- subquery returns male nurses 
                        (select p1.person_id
                          from person p1 join staff s1
                            on p1.person_id = s1.person_id
                          where s1.staff_type = 'Nurse'
                            and p1.sex = 'M'
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can use `s1.staff_type like '%Nurse'` instead of `s1.staff_type ='Nurse'`
to include senior male nurses to be excluded. And instead of not in I would suggest to use `not exists`.

```
select p.first_name, p.surname,s.staff_type,p.sex,p.town,
       extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from p.birth_date) age
from staff s join person p on s.person_id = p.person_id
where s.staff_type <> 'Surgeon'
and not exists
              (
                     select 1
                     from person p1 join staff s1
                          on p1.person_id = s1.person_id
                     where s1.staff_type like '%Nurse'
                          and p1.sex = 'M'and s1.person_id=s.person_id
              );
```